# Why PHP send binary 0x2EF5 but Javascript receive 0x2EFD?

Tags: javascript, php, file, binary

my PHP read a binary file and transfer it to Javascript client. Unfortunately,  I have a wrong parsing; for example, the HEX value *2EF5* is processed like *2EFD*.

**PHP**

```
echo file_get_contents($filepath);
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function handleDatFile(data){
    var view = new jDataView(data, undefined, undefined, true);

    parser = new jParser(view, {
        header: {
            ID: 'uint32',
            sample: 'uint32',
            analogs: [
                'array', 
                function(){
                    var v0 = this.parse(16);
                    return v0.toString(2);
                },
                8
            ],
            digitals: ['array', 4, 29]
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is only solve using headers.

in html

or
 in php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Sorry but your solution doesn't work. I've tried to add *header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');* in php side and the same in my *$.ajax* post contentype but 0xF5 is always parsed like 0xFD.